# ColdFusion 8 performing cfquery, transactions and dirty reads

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, transactions

When using ColdFusion 8 with MSSQL, when tracing, my DBA noticed the cfquery calls are getting appended with `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED` which is not in the query itself.  He recommended to remove it or change to uncommitted for performance reasons.

Is this something that ColdFusion is adding and is that by default in ColdFusion and/or MSSQL?

I am using ColdFusion's default MSSQL drivers and I am able to temporary change by using `<cftransaction isolation="read_uncommitted">` tag around each of the cfquerys.

Are there any other ways to stop that from being appended in ColdFusion or is cftransaction the best method?

Last question, when using `isolation="read_uncommitted"` why is it adding `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` before but right after the query adding `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Brandon - I have no idea why they voted my answer down.... wish they would add a comment so I would learn eh?  :)   Did you figure it out?

Comment: Your answer verified my thinking, Thanks!  I haven't found any other ways besides cftransaction so that's what I went with.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: ha - thanks Brandon... now if I could just find the sneaky dba who voted me down I'd send him a stern look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Committed is the default isolation level for any query to the DB that does not otherwise have an isolation level specified. You are changing it for the duration of your execution and then it reverts back to "committed". The creation of the statement is a part of what goes on "under the hood" as CF and the JDBC Driver work together. Using "read_uncommitted" is faster because it reads without preventing any other connection or query from altering or reading the data. So it opens up the possibility of a "dirty read" (where you are reading uncommitted and therefore possibly incorrect data) but in many cases that's not much of an issue so your DBA could be right.

Answer (score 2):

This is not being interpreted correctly, **read_committed** is an 'isolation' issue, if some other task has the table open for **update/insert/delete** the transaction that is in 'read_committed' will be held waiting for locks to be released from the table until transactions **ARE** committed. If the transaction is set for '**read_uncommitted**' it will read directly from the existing data and will NOT wait for the pending  **update/insert/delete** . Hence the term, '**Dirty**' meaning that anything pending, **not committed** will not be returned, but it won't be locked and delayed either.

Comment: Bradely, thanks for that additional comment. I never understood that nuance before. Great info!